# Override addEventListener to add 'touchstart' listener simultaneously with normal 'click' listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm forced to use a large UI framework for building a web app. The framework just adds plain "click" listener to the UI elements, but I also need some mobile event listener like "touchstart".

My approach:

```
(function() {
    Element.prototype._addEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(a, b, c) {
        this._addEventListener(a, b, c);

        if (a == "click") {
            this._addEventListener("touchstart", b, c);
        }
    };
})();
```

The second *_addEventListener* do not seem to work. Anyone have an advice?

**Update**
Just as neojg mentioned, it is not possible to do this directly in the override of the addEventListener function. I have come to this solution:

```
var list = [];

(function() {
    Element.prototype._addEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(a, b, c) {
        this._addEventListener(a, b, c);

        if (a == "click") {
            list.push(this);
        }

    };
})();

// build UI with framework
// ...

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var obj = list[i];
    obj.addEventListener("touchstart", obj.onclick);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO if an event listener was written to handle "touchstart" it will be confused to get the event object of the "click" event - each have a very different event object.
The sequence of "touchstart" "touchmove" "touchend" will never happen with just "click". Consider redesign your code or mimic the actions with some "overloaded" click that will fire "touchstart" "touchmove" "touchend" with proper event object and the use of timeout to mimic the sequence.